# Опримизация чтения/записи на диск

Tags: алгоритм, многопоточность, архитектура

Программа должна делать следующее:

- считать следующий блок из входного потока данных
- обработать его
- записать в выходной поток

В плане взаимодействия с файловой системой, действия программы похожи на работу архиватора.

Как реализовать такой функционал, чтобы алгоритм работал на скорости чтения-записи на диск? Пока на ум приходит кольцевой буфер и два потока - producer/consumer. Но ведь в современных архиваторах уже как-то решена эта проблема, и, возможно, существуют какие-то более эффективные архитектурные решения?

Comment: Может быть я наивен, но если простые действия над данными надо совершать, то почему бы не использовать цепочку конвееров потоков? В джаве к примеру это буфферизуется и данные считываются/записываются порциями.
P.S. Не верно говорить "наиболее оптимально".

Comment: А можете пояснить, что значит цепочка конвееров потоков? Просто с джавой не знаком.
P.S. За замечание спасибо. Исправил.

Comment: Цепочка потоков (stream) строится в виде цепочки (не издеваюсь, пытаюсь привести аналогию) ). Т.е. входной поток является источником для выходного (это если просто копирование), если желается преобразование определенное, то между ними вставляется еще звено - фильтр. Например, есть потоковый компрессор указываем ему в источник входной поток, а потоковый компрессор указываем в источником в выходной поток. В конструкторах классов можно указывать объемы буфферов и с помощью таймеров можно повлиять на частоту(по времени/объему) слива преобразованных данных.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Интересный вопрос. Предположим, что речь идет о 2-х файлах на диске (в файловой системе).

Если размер (и структура) выходного файла определяются при открытии входного, то я наверное попробовал бы сделать так.

Открываем входной файл и делаем `mmap()` на него с `madvise() MADV_SEQUENTIAL`. Также поступаем с выходным (здесь мы должны знать его размер). Запускаем N потоков (по числу потоков поддерживаемых аппаратурой). Каждый из них читает, обрабатывает и пишет свою последовательность блоков (через N блоков, т.е. для N=4 обрабатывает блоки 0,4,8,12 ...).

Если с выходным файлом такая штука не проходит (`mmap` для него делать не будем), то можно организовать список блоков результатов, который обрабатывается потоком записи. Здесь важно, чтобы этот поток делал "реально большие" (допустим 1MB) блоки для записи.

Не буду фантазировать дальше без деталей алгоритма обработки.

---

**UPD** [[@dm_panyushkin](/users/6483/dm_panyushkin)](/users/6483/dm_panyushkin), у меня лимит комментариев закончился, поэтому на Ваш вопрос в комментарии отвечаю здесь

```
а какие "подводные камни" бывают при записи в файл с помощью mmap()?
```

Основной "подводный камень" это необходимость знать максимальный размер результата (файла, куда будете писать) при вызове `mmap()`. Перед mmap для файла в который Вы будете писать надо задать размер файла (после open), например вызывая `ftruncate()`, а потом вызвать `mmap` с этим размером. Естественно после занесения всех данных размер файла можно скорректировать (тем же `ftruncate`).

IMHO `MADV_SEQUENTIAL` для записи не слишком критично, т.к. запись на диск происходит не сразу (если не создавать файл с флагами `O_SYNC`, `O_DIRECT`, вызывать `fsync()` и т.п.), система все равно будет пытаться оптимизировать доступ к диску с учетом IO операций всех процессов.

Кстати, при `mmap` для чтения-модификации тоже есть "камешек". Если файл нулевой длины, то работать не будет. Как ни странно, `mmap()` проходит нормально, а вот потом при обращении к данным - `SIGBUS`. Так что нулевую длину надо отслеживать о программировать отдельно.

---

Comment: Вообще, параллельное чтение файлов с диска - не очень хорошая затея.

Comment: @mikillskegg, почему? 

Реально N будет не очень большим. Система будет применять к файлу опережающее чтение в кэш файловой системы. mmap отображает часть пространства процесса на кэш. 

Скорее всего к моменту окончания обработки очередного блока, следующий уже будет прочитан с диска. IMHO все будет хорошо.

Comment: @avp, основано на литературных данных и личном опыте. Особенно, если файл большой и находится на обычном HDD. С флешем будет более-менее. Ну, а  если с магнитной ленты, то вообще кранты... )))

Comment: Спасибо! С mmap идея понравилась.Алгоритмов обработки на самом деле два разных:

1) В файле лежат группы данных переменной длины. По ним строится массив выходных данных из объектов одного типа.
2) Что-то вроде сортировки слиянием нескольких файлов в один.

Comment: Да и вообще, если бы данные помещались, я бы все в оперативке сделал. Кстати отсюда вопрос (с линуксом я мало знаком): повышается ли при использовании mmap использование оперативной памяти? Если да, то насколько?

Comment: @mikillskegg, ну Вы шутник (о ленте). 

О личном опыте (речь, конечно не о винде) параллельной многопоточной обработки файла, если можно, чуть подробней.

Собственно последовательный доступ к mmap-нутым данным очень эффективный (например, так сделано в утилите `cp`) и от размера файла видимо не зависит.

Comment: Да ничего особенного, просто пробовал, экспериментировал. При параллельном чтении  файла несколькими потоками по кусочкам процесс идет много медленнее. Правда, обычными write/read, но думаю, mmap сильно не поможет, поскольку все упирается в железо. И если маленькие файлы как-то могут кешироваться в буфере диска, то в случае больших головке придется бегать туда-сюда очень даже, на что дополнительное время и потратится.

Comment: Это естественно. 

Я то рассматриваю случай по сути последовательного прохода файла  (написал по числу потоков поддерживаемых аппаратурой), с небольшим "забеганием вперед" некоторыми потоками и подразумеваю размер блока равным блоку в файловой системе. 

Видимо на этом надо было заострить внимание.

Comment: @avp, видимо, @mikillskegg, как человек бывалый, хотел сказать, что к сожалению, даже на современном этапе чтение с диска это не параллельный процесс. С лентами, он, конечно, перегнул, но они хорошо иллюстрируют работу обычного дискового HDD: читаем блок, перемещаем головку (магнитную), и так до конца. Причем чем дальше друг от друга блоки, тем больше времени уходит на перемещение головки. Когда-то читал, что это было проблемой даже для HDD, сейчас позиционирование достаточно быстрое, но все же зависит от фрагментации. С SSD и флешью, таких проблем нет, так как нет позиционирования.

Comment: Имхо, сегодня об этом можно не задумываться, параллельная обработка файла будет все же каким-никаким, но ускорением.

При среднем времени позиционирования головки на сегодняшний день в 14,5 ms, можно прикинуть, сколько можно потерять в скорости.

Comment: Вот если считывать из файла в буфер большим куском, данные параллельно обработать и слить в новый файл, да еще все это сделать асинхронным и конвеерным, то можно получить выигрыш.

Comment: @dm_panyushkin, 

     повышается ли при использовании mmap использование оперативной памяти?

Размер виртуальной памяти процесса возрастет. Кстати, в 32-бит системе не получится так работать с файлами размером несколько гигабайт. Количество физической памяти, требуемой процессу уменьшится на размер буфера(ов) для чтения данных из файла. Просто теперь Вы адресуетесь к данным в файловом кэше (естественно для MAP_SHARED). 

@mikillskegg, почему Вы считаете, что **копирование** данных из кэша в буфер  процесса ускорит обработку?

Comment: @avp, а какие "подводные камни" бывают при записи в файл с помощью mmap()? Если я захочу сделать это, доступ к страницам тоже выставлять MADV_SEQUENTIAL?